# How could I save multiple users by using a checkbox with a ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have currently 4 entries in my `Role` table which refer to the role of a user in the website. These roles can be selected in a checkbox list with but I can't save the data that's submitted through the form. I get the following error: `'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'roles'**` in forms.py.

what an I missing here?

Here is the code:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User, Profile, Role


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(min_length=4, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Password'
    }), label='password')
    password2 = forms.CharField(min_length=4, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'
    }), label='Confirm Password')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'roles', 'password1']
        widgets = {
            'roles': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }

    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password and password2 and password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("password and confirm password is not same")
        if len(password) < 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password is very weak please enter 4 words at least')
        return password

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.staff = True
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
            self.roles.add(self.cleaned_data['roles'])
            user.save()
        return user
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from .managers import UserManager
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class Role(models.Model):
    MEMBER      = 1
    SECRETARY   = 2
    SUPERVISOR  = 3
    ADMIN       = 4

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (MEMBER, 'Member'),
        (SECRETARY, 'Secretary'),
        (SUPERVISOR, 'Supervisor'),
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
    )

    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_id_display()


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    overview = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True)


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(receiver=create_profile, sender=User)
```

**Edit with a new Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/Infrastructure_django/UserApp/More than three users/project/app1/views.py", line 16, in register
    form.save()
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/Infrastructure_django/UserApp/More than three users/project/app1/forms.py", line 36, in save
    user.roles.add(self.cleaned_data['roles'])
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 957, in add
    self._add_items(
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 232, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 266, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/medo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /register/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

also, may that can help

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy6kY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the `'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'roles'` error is because `self` in

```
self.roles.add(self.cleaned_data['roles'])
```

refers to the form and not to your user instance.

Instead you want to add to the roles of the user like so:

```
user.roles.add(self.cleaned_data['roles'])
```

Keep in mind though that when you're creating the `User` instance, you need to make sure that the `User` object is already created/saved *before* adding the roles. This is needed because in order to add the foreign key from the `ManyToMany` relationship to `User`, the `User` instance needs an `id`. This `id` is only created after saving the `User` instance. So you will have as final result something like:

```
user.save()
user.roles.add(self.cleaned_data['roles'])
```

Comment: but when I use (user) I get this error: **"<User: sam@gmail.com>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.** when I register

Comment: That makes sense as your user is not created in your database yet. You need to do a save before adding the roles with `user.save()`.

Comment: I added an explanation in my answer as to why this is needed.

Comment: it has fixed but I got another issue: **FOREIGN KEY constraint failed**

Comment: So this is unrelated to the original error and it could mean a few different things. Do you have any more information on which line is throwing this error? One option you can try is adding `blank=True, null=True` to `roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, null=True)`.  Another is verifying the contents of `self.cleaned_data['roles']`. Does it contain the correct id's of the roles?

Comment: your saying "Do you have any more information on which line is throwing this error?" I'll edit my question to show you the new full Traceback but for answering your question yes I added blank=True and I delete all migrations plus database and repeated that process again and the same error, didn't fade out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224971/discussion-between-medo-abdin-and-glenn-dj).